# Use a Bookmarklet Javascript in all opened windows/tabs?

Tags: javascript, tabs, window, bookmarklet

Is it possible ? 
I'm using Google Chrome if someone can find an extension ..

I've already looked for it , no results!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible unless you have opened all the other windows programmatically and have stored the references to the Window object instances.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible through imacros extension

[imacros TAB Functionality](http://wiki.imacros.net/TAB)

add your custom imacro script that runs your javascript